# Save shell execution output to file and display in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, shell

I know you can save the output of executing a script/file to another file by using:

```
./script.sh >> script_output.log
```

but this doesn't display the output in terminal during execution. Is there any way to also save the contents of execution in a file and display the messages in the terminal, during the script's execution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: None of those suggested using `script`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `tee`:

```
./script.sh | tee -a script_output.log
```

The `-a` parameter appends to the output file, since you used `>>` in your example.